# Shared memory read is slower with 1D vs 2D indexing in Cuda

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda

I have the following simple transpose kernel (ignore the input matrix initialization):

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

const int rows = 8192;
const int columns = 8192;
const int tile_dim = 32;


__global__ void transpose(float* in, float* out)
{
  __shared__ float tile[tile_dim][tile_dim + 1];

  int x = blockIdx.x * tile_dim + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * tile_dim + threadIdx.y;

  tile[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = in[y * columns + x];

  __syncthreads();

  x = blockIdx.y * tile_dim + threadIdx.x;
  y = blockIdx.x * tile_dim + threadIdx.y;

  out[y * columns + x] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y]; // Good
  // out[y * columns + x] = ((float*)tile)[threadIdx.x * tile_dim + threadIdx.y]; // Bad
}

int main()
{
  float *in, *out;

  size_t size = rows * columns * sizeof(float);
  cudaMalloc(&in, size);
  cudaMalloc(&out, size);

  dim3 grid(rows / tile_dim, columns / tile_dim);
  dim3 block(tile_dim, tile_dim);
  transpose<<<grid, block>>>(in, out);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  return 0;
}
```

The lines marked as "Good" and "Bad" are the ones which are causing the issue. Switching Good -> Bad causes almost a 2x runtime slowdown and shows a lot more transactions on the shared memory loads (68M vs 200k).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel has used [the "trick" with shared memory](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/) to pad the columns by 1:

```
__shared__ float tile[tile_dim][tile_dim + 1];
                                         ^^^
                                         pad
```

to allow for non-bank-conflicted row-wise and columnar access.

This line of code takes advantage of that:

```
out[y * columns + x] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];
```

this does not:

```
out[y * columns + x] = ((float*)tile)[threadIdx.x * tile_dim + threadIdx.y];
```

To get equivalent performance/indexing behavior in the "1D" case, you would need to multiply by the ***actual*** width of your shared memory allocation:

```
out[y * columns + x] = ((float*)tile)[threadIdx.x * (tile_dim+1) + threadIdx.y];
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

As an aside, I doubt that switching from this:

```
out[y * columns + x] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];
```

to this (only):

```
out[y * columns + x] = ((float*)tile)[threadIdx.x * tile_dim + threadIdx.y];
```

would give you numerically correct results (other changes would need to be made in your kernel code) but that doesn't seem to be the crux of your question.

Comment: Yeah, a simple mistake. Thank you.